# When is a $p$-local spectrum zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

I am currently reading Lurie's [notes](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/252x.html) on chromatic homotopy theory and fail to see the following remark in lecture 26:

> Remark 5. Let $X$ be a finite $p$-local spectrum. Then $H_\ast(X,\Bbb F_p) \simeq 0$ if and only if $X \simeq 0$. Moreover $H_k(X,\Bbb F_p)$ vanishes for almost all values of $k$.

The fact that $X$ is $p$-local amounts to saying that the canonical morphism $X \rightarrow S\Bbb Z_{(p)} \wedge X$ is an equivalence after smashing with the [Moore-spectrum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+spectrum) $S\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ (recall $\Bbb Z_{(p)} = \Bbb Z[q^{-1}\mid q\neq p]$). Meanwhile $H_\ast(X,\Bbb F_p) = \pi_\ast(X \wedge H\Bbb F_p)$. So the first claim becomes $X \simeq 0$ iff $X \wedge H\Bbb F_p \simeq 0$.

I don't know, whether finiteness of $X$ is crucial for this claim. If it is, I expect to use the fact, that $X$ is a cofiber of direct sums of suspensions of the $p$-local sphere $\Bbb S_{(p)} = S\Bbb Z_{(p)} \wedge \Bbb S \overset{???}= S\Bbb Z_{(p)}$. But in any case it looks like I should study $S\Bbb Z_{(p)} \wedge H\Bbb F_p$. I think by some universal coefficient type argument this has to be $S\Bbb F_p$, but then what? I also thought of using the fact that [ordinary homology spectra split](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ordinary+homology+spectra+split), but I wasn't able to conclude anything from it.

I feel like I lost track and am missing the tools to conclude a fact, which should be obvious. So I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Hm... What about $H\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $H\mathbb{Q}$ is not finite.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Ah, I thought the question was about a counterexample for non-finite cases.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I did ask, whether finiteness is crucial for this criterion. $H\Bbb Q$ shows that it is (and I should have noted that), so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a finite $p$-local spectrum.  Suppose $X \not\simeq 0$.  We shall show that $H_*(X; \mathbb{F}_p) \neq 0$.  Without loss of generality, suppose $X$ is connective (otherwise, suspend it until it is).  Since $X$ is not contractible, $\pi_*(X) \neq 0$.  Since $X$ is $p$-local, $\pi_*(X) = \pi_*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.  Thus $X$ has a homotopy group of minimal degree that is a nonzero $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module.  Since $X$ is finite, this homotopy group is finitely generated (ruling out things like $\mathbb{Q}$).
Thus, $\pi_*(X)$ contains a summand $A$ of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^m$.

By the Hurewicz theorem, this same summand appears in $H_*(X; \mathbb{Z})$.  Now consider the cofiber sequence $H\mathbb{Z} \wedge X \xrightarrow{p} H\mathbb{Z} \wedge X \to H\mathbb{F}_p \wedge X$.  In the long exact sequence of homotopy groups, the nonzero summand in integral homology identified above appears as $$\cdots \to ? \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{p} A \rightarrow ? \to \cdots.$$  But in either case $A = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p^m$, the multiplication by $p$ map has a kernel or a cokernel, which implies that $H_*(X; \mathbb{F}_p)$ is nonzero, as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wouldn't have been able to pull this off.

Comment: I actually wonder if there is a slicker proof along the lines of somehow building up $S\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \wedge X$ from $H\mathbb{F}_p \wedge X$, but couldn't find one.  So this argument about relating homotopy groups to mod $p$ homology groups was what I could come up with.

Comment: This sounds like another nice approach, but this would in particular imply that $S\Bbb Z_p$ could be build out of $H\Bbb F_p$s, right? Is this plausible? On an unrelated note: Why is the Hurewicz/Boardman map in the case above nonzero? Unfortunately I could not find applicable criterions on the nlab.

Comment: 1) I'm being deliberately vague about what "built" means.  Using totalizations, you can get from $H\mathbb{F}_p \wedge X$ to as far as the $p$-adic completion of $X$, and maybe it is possible to detect more by probing with nontrivial maps.  2) The Hurewicz theorem for spectra follows from the theorem for spaces, by noting that every connective spectrum is a colimit of CW-spectra.

Comment: Thanks again. I overread that you were choosing the obstruction in **minimal** degree. This means we can apply Hurewicz for $\Omega^\infty X$, giving us an isomorphism in the desired level...